# Gridsome Cannot destructure property `status` of 'undefined' or 'null'

Tags: wordpress, vue.js, gridsome

I just started a project with gridsome and wordpress

I did the `gridsome create project-name wordpress` and after running npm run develop i get this error

```
Cannot destructure property `status` of 'undefined' or 'null'.
    at WordPressSource.fetch (/home/pedroferreira/Documents/Projetos/imo/wp-content/themes/imo-gridsome/imo/node_modules/@gridsome/source-wordpress/index.js:171:40)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

I have found many people with the same problem but with no actual fix :/

I have also cretead an .env file with the variable `WORDPRESS_URL` but the error still happens!

I don't have any actual code to show because i haven't really started programming !

Edit

Comment: It's better/more-specific to add this issue to GitHub (Stackoverflow is not the place for solving specific code bugs/errors): https://github.com/gridsome/gridsome-starter-wordpress.  open-issue about your problem: https://github.com/gridsome/gridsome-starter-wordpress/issues/22

Comment: yeah already open an issue there , this question was quite old not sure if i should delete it.